# powerbuilder memory not freed

Tags: memory-management, powerbuilder

In application I have a task that keeps consuming memory until it crashes. Watching with processExplorer I found that the following function allocates approxmiately 50MB every time it is called (it is called 30 times). This memory is not freed when the function exits, even if I call GarbageCollect. Note that Functions called like:

```
Of_IsOrario, Of_GetCell, Of_GetRowCount, Of_GetColCOunt
```

just return values (not allocating memory)

```
long ll_file, i, j, ll_bytes, ll_fileWithTitles 
double ld_value 
string ls_line 
n_cst_string str 



ll_fileWithTitles = FileOpen( as_fileName + "text.txt", LineMode!, Write!, Shared!, Replace!, EncodingAnsi!) 
ll_file = FileOpen(as_fileName, LineMode!, Write!, Shared!, Replace!, EncodingAnsi!) 

if ll_file < 0 then 
        MessageBox("Σφάλμα", "Could not create file " + as_fileName) 
        return false 
end if 

for i = 1 to Of_GetColCount() 
        if in_tasks[i].Of_IsOrario() then 
                ls_line += "~tO" + in_Tasks[i].is_symbol 
        else 
                ls_line += "~t" + in_Tasks[i].is_symbol 
        end if                 
next 
FileWrite(ll_fileWithTitles, ls_line) 

for i = 1 to Of_GetRowCount() 
        ls_line = "" 
        for j = 1 to Of_GetColCount() 
                ld_value = -Of_GetCell(i, j) 

                if ls_line <> "" then ls_line += "~t" 
                ls_line += string(ld_value) 
        next 
        ls_line = str.Of_GlobalReplace(ls_line, ",", ".") 
        if IsNull(ls_line) then 
                ls_line = ls_line 
        end if 
        ll_bytes = FileWrite(ll_file, ls_line) 
        ls_line = string(in_matrix[i].il_agentId) + "~t" + ls_line 
        ll_bytes = FileWrite(ll_fileWithTitles, ls_line) 
next 

FileClose(ll_file) 
FileClose(ll_fileWithTitles) 

return true
```

Comment: Powerbuilder version?

Comment: Why do you have the construct `if IsNull(ls_line) then ls_line = ls_line...`.  Does it change anything? I could understand `ls_line = ""`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your version of powerbuilder is, but try replacing the IsNull ()

CR#304251 PB Enterprise Language - Runtime 8.0.3  UpperBound on an any blob 
that is not an array, and IsNull functions on a large blob are leaking 
memory. The functions are leaking when performing them on any variables. 
This is a bug, but it can't be fixed in an 8.0.3 patch. Workaround is too 
use actual datatype variables.

CR#279144 PB Enterprise DW - Runtime 8.0.1  IsNull of dot notation into 
datawindow column data is leaking memory.

CR#217105 PB Enterprise Window - Runtime 7.0.2  Memory usage goes up when 
an app is running in development or runtime (p code and machine code), when 
isnull is used with the any datatype.

[...]

It also adds the following:

```
Yield()
GarbageCollect()
```